# Make CPPickerView scroll faster with large data sources

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipickerview

I'm using [CPPickerView](https://github.com/cbpowell/CPPickerView) in my app to accomplish a horizontal UIPickerView, and it works great, but with large data sources (dozens of items) it scrolls very slowly which makes navigation before (especially considering a normal UIPickerView can go very fast through them).

I don't mean performance-wise, by the way, I mean the view decelerates very quickly, making traversal difficult.

It's just a subclass of UIScrollView with `pagingEnabled` set to `YES`. What can I do?

Comment: Have you considered that `CPPickerView` is a terrible way of picking among dozens of items?  Why not just modally present a table view or a collection view?

Comment: It's not, but kudos on the generalization.

Comment: If you using many CPPickerView? How about UITableView? UITableView can be reuse the 'Cell' so UI performance better. [UITableView Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: As mentioned, it's not a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

I looked in the source, and it seems CPPickerView is using a scroll view. Scroll views have a `decelerationRate` property. Play with that and see which value makes for the best result.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Don't fill CPPickerView with all data.
For example fill with first 20 items and if it reaches to the end add another 20.

Comment: As mentioned, it's not a performance issue, it's an acceleration issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can use the `decelerationRate` property, setting it to `UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal` might help.

```
scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
```

If that still doesn't solve your problem you could also buffer your inputs into the scroll. See this:
[Advanced scrollview techniques](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#advanced-scrollview-techniques)

Comment: That's what it's set to now. Basically, if you flick through a UIPickerView, it flies, but with CPPickerView, it goes about four values and slows to a halt.

Answer (score 0):

Creator of CPPickerView here - I've recently updated CPPickerView to add an `allowSlowDeceleration` property, which should do what you're looking for. Check out the latest code on Github, or Cocoapods version 1.2.0.

For the purposes of documentation, here's how the solution works. Like you mentioned CPPickerView just a scrollview with `pagingEnabled` set to `YES`, so the solution I found was to disable paging when the user scrolls with enough velocity.

`UIScrollViewDelegate` has an optional method `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`, which is called when the user's finger is lifted after swiping/scrolling on the scrollview, and it's still called even when paging is enabled. Based on that value you can tell if the user was trying to scroll quickly through items, or just move one or two items.

I played around with the CPPickerViews in the Demo project, and found that a velocity of about `2.9f` seems to be about the normal "fast swipe" threshold. So if the velocity is greater than this threshold (which I defined as `kCPPickerDecelerationThreshold` in `CPPickerView.m`) and `allowSlowDeceleration` is set to `YES`, CPPickerView now sets `pagingEnabled` to `NO` before the deceleration starts. This allows the picker to "coast" and decelerate like a normal scrollview.

It then catches the end of the deceleration, OR the user touching to stop the scroll, by the call to the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` delegate method. The current item is determined (based on the offset of the scrollview), and then if the scrollview's `pagingEnabled` property is set to `NO` a call to the private method `scrollToIndex:animated:` is made with animation set to `YES`. This scrolls the CPPickerView to the current item, which necessary as it's unlikely the coasting scroll ended right on a page boundary.

Finally, when the animated scroll completes, the `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` delegate method is called, at which point `pagingEnabled` is set back to `YES`.

If you find that you're having trouble getting it to recognize a "fast" swipe, try playing with the `kCPPickerDecelerationThreshold` value. In hindsight that maybe should be a customizable property, so perhaps I'll roll that into the next update.